# Recording EVERY test scenario run using intelliTest in Visual Studio 2015 RC

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, pex

While watching the intellitest explorer window during a test run, I notice that Pex runs more tests than is displayed when the run is finished. How do I ensure that all of the tests that were run are displayed in the window when run is complete? I would like to examine the intermediate tests that failed/passed and also save them for further use.

Answer (score 2):

Intellitest works on the basis of code coverage as the metric. It shows a test only if:

- Test covers a code path not previously covered
- Test is not duplicate

So the the results window actually shows all the tests covering code paths intellitest can reason about. If there's a statement in code intellitest cannot reason, it shows a warning and no test is generated.

There is a slightly different behavior if you do a "Run Intellitest" at a class level. In that case, tests are generated for each method in the class and the generated tests shown correspond to the method selected in drop down (e.g. currently only tests for `XmlObjectContext.Dispose` are shown).

[image: intellitest results]